# Calling web API and Receive return value in Android

Tags: android, api

I've googled for that topics and don't get any useful information.

I want to use Web API in my android projects, but don't know how to call them from android or java

I've got some WEB API from [this](http://uhunt.felix-halim.net/api) site and want to use in my android project.
For example, a web api `URL : /api/uname2uid/{uname}.`

that convert **User name** to **User numeric ID**

I want to display the **User ID** returned from that API into a `TextView`. So i need the return value as string or number. Please help me this.

**EDIT**
 
I just want to learn how to use WEB API 
**For more simplicity:**
In my program I have a `TextView`, a`EditText` and a `Button`
When i press the `Button` then `TextView` will update by corresponding **user ID** for **Username** given in `EditText` field thats all. An working example will be great for me to understanding this.

Comment: Consider implementing Volley in your project. Read the [guide here](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html) for more information.

Comment: You make an HTTP (or HTTPS, depending on the service) request to the URL they specified, of the type (GET, POST, DELETE, etc) they specify.  Then read the response..

Comment: Check out retrofit. A nice little library that makes this very easy and lots of tutorials around, just make sure the tutorial matches the retrofit version as there have been some big changes in v2

Comment: Just use [Ion](https://github.com/koush/ion). It's the easiest and fastest way to add networking to your app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I just want to display the the **User ID** return from the API, below the solution is work for me.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static TextView txtUserid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                    Button btnUserid = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnUserid);
        btnUserid.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new UserNameToId().execute("https://uhunt.onlinejudge.org/api/uname2uid/almaruf");
            }
        });
    }

    protected class UserNameToId extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... url) {

            try {
                URL Url = new URL(url[0]);
                URLConnection urlConnection = Url.openConnection();
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                String str = "";
                str = bufferedReader.readLine();
                return str;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            txtUserid = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUserId);
            txtUserid.setText(result);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A simple Async call would do the thing for you.:

MainActivity.java

```
new YourAsync(){

            protected void onPostExecute(Object[] result) {

                String response = result[1].toString();
                try{
                JSONObject jsonObject=(new JSONObject(jsonResult)).getJSONObject("data"); //Parsing json object named 'data'
                yourTextView.setText(jsonObject.getString("uname")); 
        }.execute(YourURL);
```

YourAsync.java

```
public class YourAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Object[]> {

    @Override
    protected Object[] doInBackground(String... params) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(params[0].toString());
        Log.d("http client post set","");

        try{
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
            Log.d("YourAsync","Executed");
            return new Object[]{response, new BasicResponseHandler().handleResponse(response)};
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("" + e, "");
        }
        return new Object[0];
    }
```

Comment: Deprecated libraries. I wouldn't use those.

Comment: Yes deprecated, but it is good than nothing. Go for volley otherwise.

Comment: The code under MainActivity.java is confusing, would you please explain the purpose of `onPostExecute` method and `JSONObject` instantiation.

Comment: @maruf: onPostExecute method in the async task is executed when the our async task is completed and we have received our response from our request. Here I assumed your response is in JSON format, so for parsing that json I have initiated the JSONObject.

Comment: is it possible without using JSON format. Sorry I don't know anything about JSON

Comment: It depends on your REST API. If your REST API is giving out json response then you will have to use json, if it is giving out xml response, then you will have to parse the XML

Answer (score 1):

```
public class JsonWebServiceCall {
// HttpURLConnection method to get JSON data from Webservice
public static String GetJsonString(String mUpdateUrl) {

    String result=null;
    try {

        URL url = new URL(mUpdateUrl);

        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        con.setAllowUserInteraction(false);
        con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(true);
        // con.setRequestMethod("POST");
        con.connect();
         if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
        // BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new
        // InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        try {
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(con.getInputStream());

            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(in));

            String json;

            while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(mUpdateUrl + "kkkkkkkkk------" + json);
                sb.append(json + "\n");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();

        }
        Log.i("json", "===" + sb.toString().trim());
        result=sb.toString().trim();}
         else{
             result=null;
         }
 return result;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

}

// HttpURLConnection method to get JSON data from Webservice
public static String PostJsonString(String mUpdateUrl, String webserviceurl) {

    // BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
    try {

        String urlParameters = mUpdateUrl;
        URL url = new URL(webserviceurl);
        URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        conn.setDoOutput(true);

        OutputStreamWriter writer = new OutputStreamWriter(
                conn.getOutputStream());

        writer.write(urlParameters);
        writer.flush();

        String line;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                conn.getInputStream()));

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        writer.close();
        reader.close();
        return sb.toString().trim();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Asynchtask..........

```
public static class AsyncCriticalMessage extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String result = null;
    CriticalMessageServiceSuccess criticalMessageServiceSuccess = null;

    public AsyncCriticalMessage(CriticalMessageServiceSuccess criticalMessageServiceSuccess) {
        this.criticalMessageServiceSuccess = criticalMessageServiceSuccess;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        result = JsonWebServiceCall.GetJsonString(Globals.FORCEUPDATE_MESSAGE_SERVICE_URL);
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void Result) {
        super.onPostExecute(Result);

        criticalMessageServiceSuccess.onSuccess(result);
    }
}
 AsyncCriticalMessage asyncCriticalMessage=new AsyncCriticalMessage(this);
    asyncCriticalMessage.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need AsyncTask to do the networking transmission and receiving using appropriate Connection classes, and finally have it return the value to the main UI thread via onPostExecute(). I am really not sure what is the sticking point that prevents you proceeding normally.

Comment: I'm completely new in Android network programming, and I've seen many examples related to network problem. But i'm really not sure what i have to done for my silly problem and how to start. The Question I've asked for knowing how to receive/use returned string. If you see the WEB API in my question then you will see that API only return an ID, I just need that return ID.

Answer (score 0):

***The accepted answer is great but***, I was wondering how it could be on **API-28** using **HttpURLConnection**? This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46803794/2227070) gave me the general idea; But it did not work for my case. I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56248480/2227070) today and it worked great. While I was searching, I saw someone(*If I find the link, I will update*) saying that it was better to use **HttpURLConnection**. For this reason, I somehow tried to get the following output from these two answers. I can't say I'm sure of this method (*Use it on your own*), but it works well for my case right now.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
        new httpURLRequest().execute("String URL");
    }


    protected class httpURLRequest extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        @Override
        public String doInBackground(String... url) {
            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            try {
                URL Url = new URL(url[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) Url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("GET");

                StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
                InputStream ins = connection.getInputStream();
                Scanner s = new Scanner(ins);
                s.useDelimiter("\\A");
                while (s.hasNext())
                    res.append(s.next());

                return res.toString();
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null)
                    connection.disconnect();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            //You can update UI here
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: one more thing is that, IDE tells me "*This AsyncTask class should be static or leaks might occur*"; I'm not sure, but it might not be a bad thing to consider, anyway.