# Run curl from Java android

Tags: java, android, curl

I have this curl command

```
curl -X GET "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q=Carlos+Vives&type=artist" -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Authorization: Bearer <My API Key>"
```

How can I run it ,and get the JSON response from Android (Java)?

Comment: You wouldn't. You'd translate it into a proper Java HTTP library method

Answer (score 5):

I've found the solution , Thanks

```
 /**
 * Gets the response from http Url request
 * @param url
 * @return
 * @throws IOException
 */
public static String getResponseFromHttpUrl(URL url) throws IOException {

    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    connection.addRequestProperty("Accept","application/json");
    connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/json");
    connection.addRequestProperty("Authorization","Bearer <spotify api key>");

    try {
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(in);
        scanner.useDelimiter("\\A");

        boolean hasInput = scanner.hasNext();
        if (hasInput) {
            return scanner.next();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    } finally {
        connection.disconnect();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can execute the command line using the following method and also you can change it to `JsonObject` using `Gson`.

```
public static String executeCommand(String command) {
    StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
    try {
      Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] { "sh", "-c", command });
      BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

      String line;
      while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
        output.append(line + "\n");
      }
      proc.waitFor();
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return output.toString();
  }
```

[EDIT]

Please this answer is never mind.

As his(cricket_007) comment, you need to use network library for Android or Java such as [OkHttp](https://github.com/square/okhttp) or [Retrofit](https://github.com/square/retrofit).

Comment: Curious if a curl still requires Asynctask

Comment: @cricket_007 you're thinking like me. I'm trying to use it now, it will be needed by stream and then I will edit my answer as well.

Comment: @cricket_007 I feel so sorry for my wrong answer and thank you so much for your feedback.

Comment: I'm sure it can be done, just really shouldn't if it can be avoided