# How to make a POST when scanning a QRCode in a JSP page

Tags: javascript, java, jsp, post

This might be an odd way to make a POST request but that's how i would like to do it.

This is the `QR Code` in a `.jsp`/`HTML` page that simply redirects you to a `URL` location, feel free to try it.

```html
<img id='barcode' style="position:absolute; TOP:70px; WIDTH:85px; HEIGHT:85px"
   src='https://api.qrserver.com/v1/create-qr-code/?data=https://www.google.com&amp;size=100x100'
   title="HELLO" width="100" height="100"/>
<div style="position:absolute; ">
   <h3>
   Visit Google</h3
</div>
```

It redirects your phone to a given `URL` after the `?data=` parameter

Is there an actual way to simulate a `POST` after scanning the `QR`, instead of redirecting the mobile's browser to the given `URL` ?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but wouldn't that depend on the QR-code reader application in the phone? I assume that most of them just check if the text contains http:// and in that case they offer you to follow link in the browser.

Comment: i used my built in my phone scanner, and it redirected me to google, so should i write let's say an app that will make the `post` through the phone?

Comment: In that case it is a question about the android/iOS application programming and not about java/jsp. For example https://www.wikihow.com/Execute-HTTP-POST-Requests-in-Android
You just have to somehow encode/decode the POST request data in the QR code. The post request can be expressed in CURL and here's a solution to execute it from Android: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46803286/run-curl-from-java-android

Comment: yes in that case it is... but are you sure there is no other way through jsp?what if if i simply do it in `JSP` and trigger it when the `QRCode` is being scanned?

Comment: What happens when the QRCode is scanned is up to your application. JSP is a server-side language producing js/html. The POST should be executed from the phone or from the server?

Comment: @NeplatnyUdaj good question,from the server i suppose when the QR is scanned,actually it's up to me.